# Написать блок с последовательностью используя LOOP (PL/SQL Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица FOR_S с двумя пустыми колонками:
S_ID  и S_TEXT.

Создана последовательность:

```
  CREATE SEQUENCE cycle_seq
  MINVALUE 0
  MAXVALUE 20  
  START WITH 0
  INCREMENT BY 2
  CYCLE
  Nocache;
```

Нужно написать блок, используя цикл LOOP и выше созданную последовательность, который заполнит 25 строк в таблице FOR_S.
Нужно чтобы данные в поле S_TEXT тоже менялись.

Ребята, подскажите как это сделать. Раньше никогда с таким не сталкивался.
Написал код, который заполняет  25 строк колонки S_ID используя последовательность.

```
 DECLARE
 c1 number:=0;
 BEGIN
 LOOP
 insert into FOR_S(S_id)
 select cycle_SEQ.nextval from dual;
 c1:=c1+1;
 exit when c1=25;
 end loop;
 end;
```

Ну как сюда применить добавить значение, чтобы заполнялись еще строки колонки S_TEXT  не знаю.

Comment: _Есть таблица S_TABLE_ и _25 строк в таблице FOR_S_, так сколько у вас таблиц?

Comment: одна  таблица. с двумя пустыми колонками. нужно чтобы цикл Loop заполнял строки. Строк должно быть 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Вот код)

```
  DECLARE
  c1 number:=0;
  с2 number:=0;
  BEGIN
  LOOP
  insert into FOR_S(S_id, S_text)
  select cycle_SEQ.nextval, sysdate + c2
  from dual;
  c1:=c1+1;
  c2:=c2+1;
  exit when c1=25;
  end loop;
  end;
```